# How set "not selected" value in <form:select> in a primitive value?

Tags: forms, spring

I'm using Spring and i would add the "not selected" value into a `<form:select>`.

```
<form:select path="country.idCountry">
    <form:option value="" label="-- Select one --" />
    <form:options items="${countries}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="idCountry" />
</form:select>
```

The field `idCountry` can't be null infact it is a `int` primitive.

If I try to execute the code I obtain this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type
```

It has a sense, the `idCountry` field can't be null, but I **want** allow to insert a "not selected" value (after with a validator I check its value).

I have found an ugly solution setting a special value for "not selected" option, like `-1` and after with the validator checking that the field isn't equal to this special value.

**There is another better way of doing this?**

Thanks.

Comment: and what would be the value of that "not selected" option? It would be something like -1 right? Not sure this has anything to do with Spring MVC actually, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Usually the "not selected" value is an empty string, but isn't correct for Spring when it tries to bind the field idCountry putting the empty string (meanwhile transformed into a null).

Comment: I still don't know what you're trying to do concretely. If you are exposing a primitive type, you have to give it a value. There's nothing Spring (or any framework) can do about it.

Comment: Now I understand. I believed that the Spring component for binding checks the field looking for annotation like `@Column(insertable=false)` or `@GeneratedValue`, if it find one of these annotation **and** the field is a primitive don't try to insert a null value into a primitive. So I put `-1` for "not selected" value and check it after with a validator.

Comment: How about changing primitive type to wrapper class? int to Integer.